# Can I disable android defualt camera (rear and front) while using a developing app using android studio

Tags: android-studio, agora.io, uvc

- I want to develop a video call app and the requirement is, there is a usb camera and i should connect it when i make a video call. then it should take video from usb camera .
- i found a uvc camera library for take camera view from usb camera and agora for video calll .
- But the problem is in agora library has been implement to choose rear and front camera and also the library is read only . i can't change code .

Any one have any idea to solve this problem and i also want to know that is there any possibility to disable front and rear camer?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the setExternalVideoSource API to set your usb camera as the video source. Take a look at this doc to understand how to custom video source: https://docs.agora.io/en/Interactive%20Broadcast/custom_video_android?platform=Android.